# How to push Magento 2 module from Composer to Github

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, amazon-web-services

I am working on payment gateway module Cybersource.

Our code on Github and we are using Amazon Web Services.

We have installed module using composer and it's working correctly but we need to add this module on github as well because after deployment in AWS the cybersource module is no present due to its accessing code from GIT.

Now we want to know how to push magento 2 module from composer to github ?

Does anyone have a work around for this.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I am facing issue to push a module which was installed using composer on server directly.Now need to push it on Github.

On github I push the following files:'

`module
composer.json
composer.lock
app/etc/config.php`
and run composer install on production server the module working as expected but on next deployment the module is not visible.

Comment: Here are the steps: https://mageprince.com/blog/add-a-module-in-the-composer-magento-2/